# MX records not correctly updated by the Google DNS servers

Tags: domain-name-system, email, domain, google, mx-record

We are currently losing some e-mail and we discovered that this is caused by a wrong DNS setting. We used a CNAME for our MX record an thats not allowed. So about 2 weeks ago we changed it to an A-record to fix the problem.

It seems all major DNS services (like OpenDNS and ISPs) have synced their records and are returning correct results on our DNS queries. But Googles DNS service (at 8.8.8.8) is still returning the CNAME values and we still some e-mails are not delivered correctly.

Query on OpenDNS:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> mx wrep.nl @208.67.222.222
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 51231
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wrep.nl.           IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
wrep.nl.        3595    IN  MX  10 druif.wrep.nl.

;; Query time: 21 msec
;; SERVER: 208.67.222.222#53(208.67.222.222)
;; WHEN: Fri Nov 25 21:36:58 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47
```

Query on Google DNS:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> mx wrep.nl @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12124
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wrep.nl.           IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
wrep.nl.        2372    IN  CNAME   druif.wrep.nl.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
wrep.nl.        572 IN  SOA ns0.freshdns.nl. hostmaster.twilightinc.nl. 2011112401 14400 3600 604800 3600

;; Query time: 94 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Fri Nov 25 21:38:10 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 117
```

So is there anyone who can explain why Google is responding with a different (incorrect) result two weeks after the last change? And how can we get Google to update their DNS records correctly? Any help is very appreciated.

(Please note that other domains that are managed by the same DNS servers/tools are working fine.)

Comment: Is there something wrong with your SOA record? `dig -t SOA wrep.nl` only returns the CNAME. Am I missing something?

Comment: Wow! A recursive CNAME! I wonder who thought that was a good idea. If `wrep.nl` is a CNAME for `druif.wrep.nl`, then `druif.wrep.nl` is a CNAME for `druif.druif.wrep.nl` and so on. Not good.

Comment: @faker Indeed strange, but I solved the problem now. See my post below in a moment.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Err, right. This is and was never the case. So don't know what you are talking about. (And if something like this was my problem you should provide some helpful tips and tricks to resolve the problem.)

Comment: @Mac_Cain13 This is a recursive CNAME: `wrep.nl.        2372    IN  CNAME   druif.wrep.nl.` This says `wrep.nl` is a CNAME for `druif.wrep.nl`, which means `druif.wrep.nl` is `druif. {CNAME for druif.wrep.nl}` or `druif.druif.wrep.nl`, and so on.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Hmm, it's not resolved that way by any tool/application I know. But it definitely is not smart to make your domain.tld record a CNAME, because it will screw things up. Like your MX records on that domain.

Comment: @Mac_Cain13 It's not resolved that way because the tools are smart enough to realize that it's meaningless nonsense. There is no coherent way to say what that's supposed to mean. A CNAME makes the source act as another name for the target. If you make `wrep.nl` act as another name for `druif.wrep.nl`, you have an infinite recursion.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Okay, I'm no DNS guru so I don't know the exact details. But this wasn't my problem in this case. Thanks for the info anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found someone with the same problem I had on the [Google public DNS Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/public-dns-discuss/browse_frm/thread/40fd55dfc03af9d9/5daa286cbae8eea3?hl=en&lnk=gst#5daa286cbae8eea3). The comment from Alex Nizhner helped me solve my problem.

It seems that if you first resolve wrep.nl and this turns out to be a CNAME to druif.wrep.nl the DNS client will cache this. If then you try to resolve the MX record for wrep.nl it will respond with the cached CNAME record and will not return the correct MX record.

So I changed wrep.nl to an A-record waited for all DNS servers to get in sync and everything is working as expected now. All mail is coming through. :)

Comment: Good to head the problem has been solved! Don't forget you can accept your own answer. This will help others with similar problems find the answer quickly.

Comment: @AronRotteveel Will do, but have to wait 11 more hours before I'm allowed to accept. :)

Answer (score 2):

I seem to be located not very far from you and get results that seem to be fine.

This issue might be caused by the fact that [Google's Public DNS servers use anycast](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/speed/public-dns/faq.html#locations) to route `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` to different datacentres, as indicated here. Perhaps there are some routing differences based on the location from which you are querying the servers. **This could easily be tested by logging into some of your servers and performing a query on the same IP-address there.**

Based on what you are writing now and what I see here, **my best bet is that the problem is based on a cached entry that is still being served from some datacentres**. If the issue persists, you might want to take it up to the [Google Public DNS usergroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/public-dns-discuss).

**Query results from *home* (Zwolle):**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> mx wrep.nl @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19924
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wrep.nl.           IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
wrep.nl.        1566    IN  MX  10 druif.wrep.nl.

;; Query time: 56 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov 26 13:41:55 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47
```

**Query results from server located in *Amsterdam*:**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-16.P1.el5_7.1 <<>> wrep.nl MX @8.8.8.8
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23370
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wrep.nl.           IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
wrep.nl.        3112    IN  MX  10 druif.wrep.nl.

;; Query time: 19 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov 26 13:42:40 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47
```

**Query results from *San Jose*:**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4 <<>> wrep.nl MX @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27967
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wrep.nl.           IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
wrep.nl.        3599    IN  MX  10 druif.wrep.nl.

;; Query time: 277 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov 26 12:44:15 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47
```

Comment: Thanks for testing and posting the results! Turned out to be an error in my DNS configuration after all (check my own answer), but your results helped me realize it wasn't Google DNS not syncing properly.

Answer (score 1):

Working fine here.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> mx wrep.nl
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 14549
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wrep.nl.           IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
wrep.nl.        2489    IN  MX  10 druif.wrep.nl.

;; Query time: 52 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Fri Nov 25 15:46:53 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47
```

Comment: Interesting, so it seems that when you query the Google DNS servers (from NY I guess?) you get other results then I get from the Netherlands. I tried on several machines to be sure it was not my machine going crazy. Starting to think there is one Google DNS machine (in Europe) not syncing records correctly. :(

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, I noticed this the other day when working on my DNS servers.

After updating a zone to add a MX record I checked Google's server to see if it would pick it up. It picked up the new SOA serial number but still cached the old MX record.

I suspect that Google's caching method caches individual records that don't get flushed when the zone serial number changes.

Comment: That's _everyone_'s caching method.  Read RFCs 1034 and 1035.